# jQuery File Upload Cakephp

Tags: jquery, cakephp, file-upload

I'm trying to get blueimp's jQuery File Upload working with Cakephp.

Everything is great except I seem to be having problems trying to delete something that has been uploaded. I get the error below in the console when I click on delete on particular file.

```
DELETE http://example.com.au/app/webroot/?file=logo%20%285%29.gif 404 (Not Found)
jquery.min.js:4XHR finished loading: "http://example.com.au/app/webroot/?file=logo%20%285%29.gif".
```

Is there a reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 5):

First of all place all necessary js and css file in webroot directory.

Place them wherever you need like place js file inside webroot/js/jquery_file_upload/ and css inside webroot/css/jquery_file_upload.

Now make one vendor directory called **UploadHandler**. Inside this directory copy paste **UploadHandler.php**.

Now you almost done.

now follow below steps.

- In view file copy paste example code which you have downloaded from [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). dont forget to give correct path to each js and css files and in form **make sure name for file input type is files[ ]**.
- now created one controller action in which actual magic will happen. copy paste following code and define path as your requirement.

```
<?php
class ServicePicturesController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'ServicePictures';

    function upload()
    {
        $this->layout = "ajax";
        App::import('Vendor','UploadHandler',array<'file' => 'UploadHandler/UploadHandler.php'));

        $options = array
        (
            'script_url' => SITE_URL.'service_pictures/upload/',
            'upload_dir' => APP.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'img'.DS.'offer_picture'.DS,
            'upload_url' => SITE_URL.'img/offer_picture/',
            'max_number_of_files' => 3,
            'thumbnail' => array
            (
                'max_width' => 150,
                'max_height' => 150
            )
        );

        $upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options, $initialize = false);
        switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])
        {
            case 'HEAD':
            case 'GET':
                $upload_handler->get();
                break;
            case 'POST':
                $upload_handler->post();
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                $upload_handler->delete();
                break;
            default:
                header('HTTP/1.0 405 Method Not Allowed');
        }
        exit;
    } ?>
```

I have done it successfully after spending 2 hours and tested it.

you can also integrate database into this.

feel-free to ask more.

Hope this will help you and other programmer brothers.

**Download the example code from the link which i mentioned in first step in follow below steps.**

Place js and css file as your want but place it inside webroot for cakephp conventions.

Cheers.